# Is there a way to programmatically perform a swipe action on a radlistview item?

Tags: android, nativescript, swipe, radlistview

I am using nativescript & angular and I have a RadListView with tap-to-execute swipe actions. Left swipe shows a delete button , right swipe shows an "options" button.

After the items are loaded I want to **programmatically swipe to the right** the first item. I know I can get the view of the first item with getViewItemAt(O) but I don't know if it's possible or how to apply a programatic swipe gesture to it

Comment: I doubt the feature is supported out of the box, you might want to raise a request at https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

If anyone else is looking for this it can be achieved by simply animating the item view

```html
... items loaded ... then 
{
    let item = this.radList.listView.getItemAtIndex(0);
    let view = this.radList.listView.getViewForItem(item);
    setTimeout(()=> {
        //animate on x axis - will show the swipe action at the right 
        view.animate({
            translate: { x: 80, y: 0},
            duration: 50,
            curve: AnimationCurve.spring
        });
        //animate back to hide it
        setTimeout(()=> {
            view.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: 0},
                duration: 50,
                curve: AnimationCurve.spring
            });
        }, 1000);

    }, 2000);  
}
...
```

Comment: I can get this working on Android.  On iOS, the item movement is animated but the swipe actions are not visible.  If this worked on both platforms for you, can you share the styling you used?